# PHP protected classes and properties, protected from whom?

Tags: php, oop, protected

I'm just getting started with OOP PHP with *PHP Object-Oriented Solutions* by David Powers, and am a little curious about the notion of protection in OOP.

The author clearly explains how protection works, but the bit about not wanting others to be able to change properties falls a bit flat. I'm having a hard time imagining a situation where it is ever possible to prevent others from altering your classes, since they could just open up your `class.php` and manually tweak whatever they pleased seeing as how PHP is always in plain text.

Caution: all of the above written by a beginner with a beginner's understanding of programming.

Comment: Besides "protection" it is also implicit documentation. Someone reading your code knows that `private` methods are only used internally in the class. `protected` methods can be called by subclasses. And `public` methods are the one to use in order to interact with an object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From yourself!

You use various levels of protection to indicate how you want a class to be used. If a class member is `protected` or `private`, it can only be accessed by the class itself. There's no chance you can screw up the value of that member accidentally from "external" code (code outside the class).

Say you have a class member that is only supposed to contain numbers. You make it `protected` and add a setter which checks that its value can only be numeric:

```
class Foo {

    protected $num = 0;

    public function setNum($num) {
        if (!is_int($num)) {
            throw new Exception('Not a number!!!');
        }
        $this->num = $num;
    }
}
```

Now you can be sure that `Foo::$num` will always contain a number when you want to work with it. You can skip a lot of extra error checking code whenever you want to use it. Any time you try to assign anything but a number to it, you'll get a very loud error message, which makes it very easy to find bugs.

It's a restriction you put on yourself to ease your own work. Because programmers make mistakes. Especially dynamically typed languages like PHP let you silently make a lot of mistakes without you noticing, which turn into very hard to debug, very serious errors later on.

By its very nature, software is very *soft* and easily degrades into an unmaintainable Rube Goldberg logic machine. OOP, encapsulation, visibility modifiers, [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) etc are tools PHP gives you to make your code "harder", to express your intent of what you want certain pieces of your code to be and enable PHP to enforce this intent for you.

Comment: You summed up in the first 3 sentences what blogs and documentation sites do in 3 paragraphs. Thanks for being so succinct.

Answer (score 6):

Protected is not really protecting from anyone to change the source code, but is just a [class method visibility in PHP OOP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

> Class members declared public can be accessed everywhere. Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inherited and parent classes. Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.

Answer (score 2):

They mean they are protected in different ways...

- *Private* variables are not visible to anywhere except from within the class.
- *Protected* variables are not visible to the instantiated object, but *are* visible to classes which inherit from that class, as well as the class itself.

Nothing stops another programmer from opening a class file and changing the access modifiers.

The hiding of data is a good thing because the less you expose, the more you can control and less bugs you can potentially introduce.

Comment: "the more you can control" ... from yourself and/or coworkers?

Comment: @Andrew Heath Both. If you have a class property called `$data` which should not be accessed directly, make it `private`. You can then use a method to return it (and do any necessary pre-processing).