# Get id from object

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, object

I'm working with an api and I it returns these values:

```
CultuurNet\Auth\User Object ( [id:protected] => c23e4336-8f84-4501-9253-8b2faage5291 [tokenCredentials:protected] => CultuurNet\Auth\TokenCredentials Object ( [token:protected] => 7f0be1ffab3a456a8a8aa5efeea86c1f [secret:protected] => ab3c927180d7854de0e8e5842a21bc92f ) )
```

How can I retreave the [id:protected] from it in php?

Comment: Can't. protected members are only accessible from within the class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643274/php-protected-classes-and-properties-protected-from-whom

Comment: Only public properties/methods are retrievable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you tested for a getter method? Something like

```
$object->getId();
```

If a getter does not exist, you can use reflection, see the answer of Maxim Khan-Magomedov.

Answer (score 0):

Use [reflections](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php).

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($user);
$property = $reflection->getProperty('id');
$property->setAccessible(true);

$id = $property->getValue($user);
```

But true way is using getters/setters.

Comment: Gives back a warning
ReflectionProperty::getValue() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: @Miaw what warning exactly? `$user` here is instance of `CultuurNet\Auth\User`, of course. See update (it was expecting instance).

Comment: I forgot to pass `$user` to `getValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

Extend CultuurNet\Auth\User with a class of your own make, and then present a get_id() function that returns the protected variable.

```
class MyUser extends CultuurNet\Auth\User {
  function get_id() {
    return $this->id;
  }
}
```

Comment: He states that objects are returned, and you cannot extend an object, only classes. So this will not work.